# How to iterate over an array with its elements and some other variable derived from each element

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, each

I'm trying to find a one-liner or better way to get `scope` and `scope_capitalized`. How can I do it?

- I need `scope` and `scope_capitalized` both assigned
- Instantiating variables is NOT an option

Code so far

```
['users', 'companies'].each do |scope|
  scope_capitalized = scope.capitalized
  # do stuff with scope and scope_capitalized
end

# if I had ['users', 'companies'] in a variable 'a' I could do
a.zip(a.map(&:capitalized)).each do |scope, scope_capitalized|
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "get scope and scope_capitalized"? So far your code seems sound. What else do you want to do with those variables?

Comment: `Instantiating variables is NOT an option` So you want someone to do your homework for you?

Comment: How dumb a homework would be if a professor asks for a one-liner

Comment: Just because something seems dumb, does not mean it will not be assigned as homework :)

Comment: If this isn't homework, what is restricting your ability to instantiate variables? Perhaps you have another problem elsewhere in your code.

Comment: What if I'm making a meta language over ruby that do not need variables and I'm asking you guys to help me solve this problem my language has :)

Comment: One more downvote and I'm done with this question! I'm here editing to improve, I'm saying it's not a homework and I'm providing anything someone may need...

Comment: Perhaps adding some legitimate background information would be helpful and would dissuade downvoters? To be honest, the question seems mostly fine if a little "homeworky" due to the odd restrictions of one-liner and no variables allowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
%w(users companies).map{|s|[s, s.capitalized]}.each do |scope, scope_capitalized|
  ...
end
```

This bypasses instantiation

Comment: Nice! But I think there isn't room for improvement that way

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how you intend to act on the data, you might do something like this, where you first create an array containing the pairs:

```
terms = ['users', 'companies']
terms_with_capitals = terms.map{ |scope| [scope, scope.capitalized] }
terms_with_capitals # => [['users', 'Users'],['companies','Companies']]
```

Comment: I'm not able to instantiate variables

Comment: so just chain it together `['users', 'companies'].map{ |scope| [scope, scope.capitalized] }.each {|scope, scope_capitalized| ... }`

Answer (score 1):

`['users','companies'].map(&:capitalize)` would return an array of capitalized items as a one-liner. However, if you're trying to "do stuff" with the capitalized string, a one-liner may not be a good idea because you could end up with a very long, unintelligible chain of things. White space doesn't cost anything, and readability is always favorable. Frankly, I would do something like this:

```
%w(users companies).map(&:capitalize).each do |scope|
  # do scope stuff
end
```

Comment: I need both `scope` and `scope_capitalized`

Comment: Then what kevin wrote, or what you have is perfectly fine :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question has all the information you need really. You say:

```
# if I had ['users', 'companies'] in a variable 'a' I could do
a.zip(a.map(&:capitalized)).each do |scope, scope_capitalized|
```

So then just put your array in place of `a`

```
['users', 'companies'].zip(['users', 'companies'].map(&:capitalized)).each do |scope, scope_capitalized|
```

Comment: That's not well written...I'm mean it's a solution but it should be a better way don't you think?